# Java got error on console.printf

Tags: java, netbeans

I have type following code in Netbeans but I got error

```
package learn.java;

import java.io.Console;

public class LearnJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Console console = System.console();
       console.printf("Hello My Name Is , Nitesh");
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at learn.java.LearnJava.main(LearnJava.java:8) C:\Users\The Alian\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you enabled the console? Check here for instructions: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml

Failing that, you could replace the Console call with a simple

```
System.out.println("Hello My Name Is , Nitesh");
```

or for formatted strings:

```
String name = "Nitesh";
System.out.format("Hello My Name Is , %s", name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write formatted string at **std out** by call:

```
System.out.printf("Hello My Name Is %s", "Nitesh");
```

Also, you can write error messages to **err out**:

```
System.err.printf("Some problem %s", "error message");
```

Comment: _System.err.printf_ not System.out.printf. Please update your syntax.